# golf mk4 1.6 sr engine swarp to 2.0 AZJ

Tags: vw, golf, engine-swap

good day. iam trying to change my AKL 1.6 motor to a AZJ 2.0 motor.is it a possible thing? and what else would i have to change

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Engine swaps are always possible, just depends on your knowledge, time, and pocketbook. What is it you've accomplished so far?